# PIC18 XC8 Bootloader not mapped to correct address

Tags: linker, bootloader, microchip, pic18, xc8

I'm writing a bootloader for a PIC18F87K22. I used the `-mrom` command line argument recommended in their [documentation/webinar](https://www.microchip.com/stellent/groups/SiteComm_sg/documents/DeviceDoc/en558478.pdf) to limit the Range that the compiler would place things into ROM between 0x0000-0x0FFF which should give me 4K to write the bootloader in. However when using that flag I get the linker error

> :0:: error: (500) undefined symbols:

I found that if I expand the range to be from 0x0000-0xFFFF then it builds correctly, but currently, my code is fairly simple and only uses 258 bytes and it should easily fit in the space allotted. for some reason, the compiler will not place any code in between the interrupt vectors which end at 0x001C and the address 0x1000, so this nearly 4k region of flash is going to waste. Application memory constraints are already getting tight and I really can't afford this overhead. Any ideas would be helpful. I'm currently using xc8 v2.20.

Here is the relevant section of my map file when building in the range 0x0000-0xFFFF

> ```
> Machine type is 18F87K22
>             Name                               Link     Load   Length Selector   Space Scale
> /tmp/xcXmJhLIj.o
>             idloc                            200000   200000        8        0       5
>             config                           300000   300000        E        0       4
>             init                                  0        0        4        0       0
> dist/default/production/PIC-18F87K22-BOOTLOADER.X.production.o
>             idloc                            200000   200000        8        0       5
>             config                           300000   300000        E        0       4
>             smallconst                         1000     1000       14      800       0
>             text3                              10B8     10B8       3C      80A       0
>             text2                              1014     1014       66      80A       0
>             text1                              107A     107A       3E      80A       0
>             text0                              10F4     10F4       14      80A       0
>             cstackCOMRAM                          1        1        A        1       1
>             cinit                              1108     1108        E      80A       0
>
> TOTAL       Name                               Link     Load   Length     Space
>     CLASS   STACK          
>
>     CLASS   CODE           
>             init                                  0        0        4         0
>             text3                              10B8     10B8       3C         0
>             text2                              1014     1014       66         0
>             text1                              107A     107A       3E         0
>             text0                              10F4     10F4       14         0
>             cinit                              1108     1108        E         0
>
>     CLASS   CONST          
>
>     CLASS   SMALLCONST     
>             smallconst                         1000     1000       14         0
>
>     CLASS   MEDIUMCONST    
>
>     CLASS   COMRAM         
>             cstackCOMRAM                          1        1        A         1
>
>     CLASS   ABS1           
>
>     CLASS   BIGRAM         
>
>     CLASS   RAM            
>
>     CLASS   BANK0          
>
>     CLASS   BANK1          
>
>     CLASS   BANK2          
>
>     CLASS   BANK3          
>
>     CLASS   BANK4          
>
>     CLASS   BANK5          
>
>     CLASS   BANK6          
>
>     CLASS   BANK7          
>
>     CLASS   BANK8          
>
>     CLASS   BANK9          
>
>     CLASS   BANK10         
>
>     CLASS   BANK11         
>
>     CLASS   BANK12         
>
>     CLASS   BANK13         
>
>     CLASS   BANK14         
>
>     CLASS   BANK15         
>
>     CLASS   SFR            
>
>     CLASS   CONFIG         
>             config                           300000   300000        E         4
>
>     CLASS   IDLOC          
>             idloc                            200000   200000        8         5
>
>     CLASS   FARRAM         
>
>     CLASS   EEDATA         
>
>
>
> SEGMENTS        Name                        Load    Length   Top    Selector   Space  Class
>
>             reset_vec                      000000  000004  000004         0       0  CODE    
>             text2                          001014  000102  001116       80A       0  CODE    
>             cstackCOMRAM                   000001  00000A  00000B         1       1  COMRAM  
>             smallconst                     001000  000014  001014       800       0  SMALLCON
> ```

Comment: Maybe this helps:https://www.microchip.com/forums/m833484.aspx

Comment: @Mike i read through the entire thread and it seems like the op has a very similar problem, unfortunately it is never resolved.